# SQL Server group by date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have a range of dates defined by a set of business rules.

```
CREATE TABLE #end_of_week_range
    ([id] int, [year] int, [week] int, [first_day] datetime, [last_day] datetime);

INSERT INTO #end_of_week_range
    ([id], [year], [week], [first_day], [last_day])
VALUES
    (1, 2014, 1, '2013-12-05 00:00:00', '2014-01-05 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2015, 1, '2014-12-04 00:00:00', '2015-01-04 00:00:00'),
    (3, 2014, 10, '2014-02-09 00:00:00', '2014-03-09 00:00:00'),
    (4, 2015, 10, '2015-02-08 00:00:00', '2015-03-08 00:00:00'),
    (5, 2014, 11, '2014-02-16 00:00:00', '2014-03-16 00:00:00'),
    (6, 2015, 11, '2015-02-15 00:00:00', '2015-03-15 00:00:00'),
    (7, 2014, 12, '2014-02-23 00:00:00', '2014-03-23 00:00:00'),
    (8, 2015, 12, '2015-02-22 00:00:00', '2015-03-22 00:00:00'),
    (9, 2014, 13, '2014-02-28 00:00:00', '2014-03-28 00:00:00'),
    (10, 2015, 13, '2015-02-28 00:00:00', '2015-03-28 00:00:00');
-- Many more, see SQLFiddle
```

And sales records with dates.

```
CREATE TABLE #sales (id INT, saledate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO #sales (id, saledate)
VALUES 
    (1, '2014-02-08'),
    (2, '2015-02-08'),
    (3, '2015-02-08'),
    (4, '2015-02-08'),
    (5, '2015-02-08'),
    (6, '2014-02-08'),
    (7, '2014-02-08'),
    (8, '2014-02-08'),
    (9, '2015-02-08'),
    (10, '2015-02-08'),
    (11, '2015-07-08');
```

I want to count the number of sales records in each range and receive this expected output.

```
year    week    cnt
2014    6   4
2015    6   0
2014    7   4
2015    7   6
2014    8   4
2015    8   6
2014    9   4
2015    9   6
-- More rows, see SQLFiddle
```

What I am doing right now, is looping through each range and filtering on the first and last days in the date range.

```
CREATE TABLE #sales_trended (
    [year] INT
    ,[week] INT
    ,[cnt] INT
    )

DECLARE @id INT

WHILE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #end_of_week_range
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = id
    FROM #end_of_week_range

    INSERT INTO #sales_trended
    SELECT (
            SELECT year
            FROM #end_of_week_range
            WHERE id = @id
            ) AS year
        ,(
            SELECT week
            FROM #end_of_week_range
            WHERE id = @id
            ) AS week
        ,count(*) AS cnt
    FROM #sales s
    WHERE (
            s.saledate >= (
                SELECT first_day
                FROM #end_of_week_range
                WHERE id = @id
                )
            AND s.saledate < (
                SELECT last_day
                FROM #end_of_week_range
                WHERE id = @id
                )
            )

    DELETE #end_of_week_range
    WHERE id = @id
END

SELECT *
FROM #sales_trended
```

Can I instead join the sales and date ranges tables and group by date ranges instead of looping through each date range? My current approach seems absurdly slow.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aaec8/2

Comment: Great description. I understand you fiddle work, but you want it to be faster? How fast is now? And when you say filter first and last mean IF days `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` only  count `[2,3,4,5,6]` or count `[1,7]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but can't you just join the tables with the date range, something like this:

```
select e.year, e.week, count(s.id)
from end_of_week_range e
left outer join sales s on 
  s.saledate >= e.first_day and 
  s.saledate < e.last_day
group by e.year, e.week
order by e.year, e.week
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aaec8/12)

Edit: Oops, the count must of course be something from sales

Comment: I would change the order to `e.week, e.year` for some reason that is OP expect output.

Comment: Not sure if he really expects that. The data seems to be in varchar order (1, 10...19, 2) but it's easy to assign the correct order

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL and you're thinking you need to use a loop, you're almost always thinking wrong.

You can do this with a simple join:

```
SELECT r.year,
    r.week,
    COUNT(s.id) as cnt
FROM end_of_week_range r
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON  s.saledate >= r.first_day
    AND s.saledate <  r.last_day
GROUP BY r.year,
    r.week
ORDER BY r.year, 
    r.week
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking. Thanks!